# Device licensed app does not support in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

One of my users is getting the error message:

> **In-app purchase is not supported.**
>   Device licensed app does not support in-app purchase.

On a non-consumable in-app purchase.

[image: Device licensed app does not support in-app purchase]

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: 2019: *I have no idea what is causing this error, it seems a major issue with the App Store.* https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250605906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the device is restricted by an MDM (Mobile Device Management) tool in an enterprise environment.   In app purchases are restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that:

> In-app purchases aren't shared with family members in Family Sharing.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202023